# Is synchronized(hashmap.get(data)) thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

Suppose that i have a java class called Foo containing one attribute that is a `ConcurrentHashMap` called h.

Suppose also that `Foo` class has 2 methods defined like this:

```
public void fooMethod1() {
    synchronized(this.h.get("example")) {
        ...
    }
}

public void fooMethod2() {
    synchronized(this.h.get("example")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Suppose now that it's called first `fooMethod1()` and after `fooMethod2()` from 2 different threads.

I don't know if it's possible that between `this.h.get("example")` call in `fooMethod1()` and the synchronization of object returned by the above `get`, there can be the interleaving of `this.h.get("example")` call in `fooMethod2()`.

Comment: Two threads could perform the `h.get("example")` at the same time, then one of the threads would wait for the other when it tries to enter the synchronized block (assuming the `get`-call returns the same object for both threads).

Comment: We don’t know what the code you replaced with three dots will be doing, but from all we can derive from its surroundings, it is very likely to be unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if it's possible that between `this.h.get("example")` call in `fooMethod1()` and the synchronization of object returned by the above get, there can be the interleaving of `this.h.get("example")` call in `fooMethod2()`.

Yes, there could be interleaving at the point you indicate.

The `synchronized` mutual exclusion is on the *result* of the respective `get` calls, not on the `get` calls themselves.

So if a third thread is updating the map, the two `get("example")` calls could return different values, and you would not get mutual exclusion on the same map entry.

Secondly, in the following snippet:

```
synchronized(this.h.get("example")) {
    ...
}
```

only the code in the `{ ... }` block gets mutual exclusion.

A third thing to note is that `this.h` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe unless `h` has been declared as `final`.

---

Finally, it is next to impossible to say whether this is thread-safe or not thread-safe.  Thread safety is a rather difficult property to define precisely, but it informally it means that the code will behave as expected (or as specified) irrespective of the number of threads, and for all possible execution interleaving patterns.

In your example, you don't provide enough of the code, and you don't clearly state what your expectations are.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in the matter, but your code does look thread-safe to me.

In your snippet, I assume the `ConcurrentMap` named `h` already exists and is never replaced, so we do not have a CPU core cache visibility problem with regard to that object existing or not. So no need to mark the `ConcurrentMap` as `volatile`.

Your `h` map is a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), which is a [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html). So multiple threads calling `get` method simultaneously is safe.

I assume we are certain a mapping exists for the key `"example"`. And `ConcurrentHashMap` does not allow null values, so if you have the key put into the map, there must be a value there to for us to retrieve and lock.

Both of your methods synchronize on the same intrinsic lock of whatever object is being retrieved from the concurrent map. So whichever of the two methods in different threads first get access to the object retrieved from the map wins, gains a lock per `synchronized` while the other thread waits until that lock is released. I am assuming, of course, that the map entry for the key of `"example"` is not changing during the run of our threads.

The `get` method on the map must return the very same object in order for both threads to synchronize. This is the main weakness I see in your scheme. I would recommend you take a different approach in coordinating your two threads. But, technically, if all these conditions hold true, your current code should work.

### Example code

Here is a full example along the lines of your code.

We establish your `Foo` object, which in its constructor instantiates and populates a `ConcurrentMap` named `map` (rather than `h` in your code).

Then we launch a pair of threads, each calling one of the two methods.

We immediately sleep the second method to help ensure the first thread proceeds ahead. We cannot know for sure which thread runs first, but a long sleep can help get them into the order we intend for this experiment.

While that second method is sleeping in its thread, the first method in its thread grabs the intrinsic lock of the `String` containing the word "cat". We retrieve that object in a thread-safe manner by calling `get` on a `ConcurrentMap`.

The first method then goes to sleep while holding this lock. By looking at the output on the console, we can deduce that the second method in its thread must be in a wait state, awaiting release of the `"cat"` string's lock.

Eventually the first method wakes, continues, and releases the cat-lock. By console output, we can see the second method's thread gains the cat-lock and continues on with its work.

This code uses the simple new try-with-resources syntax and virtual threads being brought to us by [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main). I am running with a [preliminary build](http://jdk.java.net/loom/) of Project Loom based on early-access Java 16. But the Loom stuff is beside the point here, and this demo could work with old-school code. This Project Loom code here is simpler, cleaner.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Foo
{
    private ConcurrentMap < Integer, String > map = null;

    public Foo ( )
    {
        this.map = new ConcurrentHashMap <>();
        this.map.put( 7 , "dog" );
        this.map.put( 42 , "cat" );
    }

    public void fooMethod1 ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Starting fooMethod1 at " + Instant.now() );
        synchronized ( this.map.get( 42 ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "fooMethod1 got the intrinsic lock on cat string. " + Instant.now() );
            // Pause a while to show that the other thread must be waiting on on the intrinsic `synchronized` lock of the String "cat".
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println( "Continuing fooMethod1 at " + Instant.now() );
        }
    }

    public void fooMethod2 ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Starting fooMethod2 at " + Instant.now() ); // Sleep to make it more likely that the other thread gets a chance to run.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 2 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        synchronized ( this.map.get( 42 ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "fooMethod2 got the intrinsic lock on cat string. " + Instant.now() );
            System.out.println( "Continuing fooMethod2 at " + Instant.now() );
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Starting run of  `main`. " + Instant.now() );
        Foo app = new Foo();
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            executorService.submit( ( ) -> app.fooMethod1() );
            executorService.submit( ( ) -> app.fooMethod2() );
        }
        // At this point, flow-of-control blocks until submitted tasks are done. Then executor service is automatically shutdown as an `AutoCloseable` in Project Loom.
        System.out.println( "INFO - Done running `main`. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
INFO - Starting run of  `main`. 2021-01-05T23:35:25.804193Z
Starting fooMethod1 at 2021-01-05T23:35:25.871971Z
fooMethod1 got the intrinsic lock on cat string. 2021-01-05T23:35:25.888092Z
Starting fooMethod2 at 2021-01-05T23:35:25.875959Z
Continuing fooMethod1 at 2021-01-05T23:35:30.893112Z
fooMethod2 got the intrinsic lock on cat string. 2021-01-05T23:35:30.893476Z
Continuing fooMethod2 at 2021-01-05T23:35:30.893784Z
INFO - Done running `main`. 2021-01-05T23:35:30.894273Z
```

**Beware:** Text sent to `System.out` does not always print out on console in expected order. Verify the time stamps to be sure of what ran when. In this example run, the third line `Starting fooMethod2` actually happened before the second line `fooMethod1 got the intrinsic lock`.

So I will manually re-arrange them into chronological order.

```
INFO - Starting run of  `main`. 2021-01-05T23:35:25.804193Z
Starting fooMethod1 at 2021-01-05T23:35:25.871971Z
Starting fooMethod2 at 2021-01-05T23:35:25.875959Z
fooMethod1 got the intrinsic lock on cat string. 2021-01-05T23:35:25.888092Z
Continuing fooMethod1 at 2021-01-05T23:35:30.893112Z
fooMethod2 got the intrinsic lock on cat string. 2021-01-05T23:35:30.893476Z
Continuing fooMethod2 at 2021-01-05T23:35:30.893784Z
INFO - Done running `main`. 2021-01-05T23:35:30.894273Z
```